# Asynchronous tasks c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am trying to understand asynchronous programming in C#. I created an example of a function that can be called only once. For example reading from a big file. I want to create a query and request will wait in query until they can safely read file.

```
AsyncWork aw = new AsyncWork();

Task.Run(() => {
    for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
        aw.DoAsyncWork(count);
        Console.WriteLine("request added");
    }
});
Console.ReadKey();
```

and `AsyncWork`

```
public class AsyncWork {
    int Requests = 0;
    int Workers = 0;

    public AsyncWork() { }

    public async Task DoAsyncWork(int count) {
        Requests++;

        while (Workers > 0) ;

        Workers++;
        Requests--;

        if (Workers > 1) Console.WriteLine("MORE WORKERS AT ONCE");

        Console.WriteLine(count.ToString() + " Started task");
        //reading from file
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine(count.ToString() + " Ended task");

        Workers--;
    }
}
```

I expected that I will have 10 requests and then they will be done one by one. But output is like:

```
0 Started task
request added
0 Ended task
1 Started task
request added
1 Ended task
2 Started task
request added
2 Ended task
3 Started task
request added
3 Ended task
4 Started task
request added
4 Ended task
5 Started task
request added
5 Ended task
6 Started task
request added
6 Ended task
7 Started task
request added
7 Ended task
8 Started task
request added
8 Ended task
9 Started task
request added
9 Ended task
```

Why it is running synchronously?

Comment: Your method `DoAsyncWork` is performed async but you have a loop in the task, that executes every time that method, so what do you expect?

Comment: I expected, that async method without await will be started and main program will continue to next line and loop will be performed in another task asynchronous.

Comment: You're not running anything async since your lambda isn't marked as `async` and you're not `await`ing `DoAsyncWork`.

Comment: @KennethK. That's not true.  Calling an asynchronous method and not awaiting it does't make the method synchronous, it makes it asynchronous, it just means that the method will continue on without the asynchronous method having completed, which is rarely desirable, but is certainly possible, and is asynchronous.

Comment: What is the meaning of this: `while (Workers > 0) ;`?

Comment: It makes all request wait (be stuck in loop) while only one is allowed to do work

Answer (score 4):

When you run the code your first worker will start working, then the next will get stuck in the busy loop that you have, `while (Workers > 0) ;` and won't move on until the previous worker finishes.  Then when it starts the next worker will be stuck there, and so on, for each iteration of the loop in which you start the workers.

So you only ever have at most one worker doing work, and one worker pegging an entire CPU sitting there waiting for it to finish.

A proper way to synchronize access when writing asynchronous code is to use a `SemaphoreSlim` and use `WaitAsync`, which will *asynchronously* wait until the semaphore can be acquired, rather than synchronously blocking the thread (and pegging the CPU while you're at it) for the other workers to finish.  It also has the advantage of being safe to access from multiple threads, unlike an integer which is *not* safe to change from multiple threads.

Comment: Oh, so this one worker stuck in loop will block main thread from creating another workers? I did not expected that on multicore processor.

Comment: @110mat110 Well you're running that whole outer loop on a thread pool thread, not the main thread, but they're still all running in that same thread pool thread.  It will only use multiple threads when you tell it to by calling an operation that schedules work to run on another thread, i.e. `Task.Run`.  Of course, if you were actually running that code in another thread you'd be introducing tons more problems (because as mentioned, you're not properly synchronizing around access to the integer).  At the moment you never have more than one thread at a time manipulating it.

Comment: Okey, so I understand, async does not mean multihread and I am mistaking it with tasks. I have a lot to learn.